# Monotone conservation of a family of families with lower bound equal to 0

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $(A,<_A,0_A)$ and $(B,<_B,0_B)$ be partial ordered sets and $\psi$ an increasing surjection from $A$ to $B$ such that $\psi^{-1}(0_B)=\left\{0_A\right\}$. If $P\subset A$ has a greater lower bound for $<_A$, we denote it by $\inf_A P$

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal and

$F: \alpha\times \alpha \to A$ an application with the following properties :

1)For any  $y,z,t\in \alpha$ we have $t\leq z\Rightarrow\psi(F(z,y))<_B\psi (F(t,y))$

($\psi\,o\, F(.,y)$ is **decreasing**)

2) $\forall (x,y)\in \alpha^2$, $y\leq x\Rightarrow F(x,y)=F(y,y)$

3)$\forall x\in \alpha,\,\,\inf_A F(x,A)=0_A$

4) $\psi\,\,o\,\,F$ is not constant

"Questions" :

a) Do we have $\inf_A(\left\{F(y,y),y\in \alpha\right\})=0_A$ ?

b) Same question if $(A,<_A)$ and $(B,<_B)$ are lattices

c) Same question if $A$ is a lattice

"Motivation"

If $u,v$ are infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, we define $<_b$ as follow :

$u<_b v$ if and only if there exists $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\in \mathbb N$, $u^*(n+a)+b>v^*(n+c)+d$ where $u^*$  is the only increasing bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $u$.

If $u$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb N$ we state that $u<_b v$ for any $v\subset \mathbb N$.

$<_b$ is a preorder on $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and if we call $b$ the associated equivalent relation, we say that $B=:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)/b$ is canonically ordered by $<_B$ (such that $u<_b v$ if and only if $[u]_b<_B[v]_b$, where $[u]_b$ denote the class of $u$ under $b$, meaning all subsets $u'$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $u<_b u'$ and $u'<_b u$ both hold).

If $A$ is $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)/a$ where $a$ is the equality up to finite subset, and $<_a$ the inclusion "up to finite subset" (meaning  for any $u,v\subset \mathbb N$, $u\subset v \cup f$ for some finite $f\subset \mathbb N$) we define $<_A$ to be such that $u<_a v\Leftrightarrow [u]_a<_A [v]_a$

Then if question a) is true at least in this very case, then it should not be difficult (*) to build from any $F\subset A$ with greater lower bound $0_A=0_B=0$,   $T\subset A$ with lower bound $0$, such that the restriction of $<_A$ to $T$ is a total order. It is a result proved (I think in 2015) by Malliaris ans Shelah, but you need to be aware of set theory to understand the proof, and I'm far to be able to!  I'm looking for a simple argument, after I read the Tim Gowers web blog, indeed the great mathematician hoped for a simple argument, but It seams  that the problem is so difficult that he left away this hope,  so it would really be astonishing if question a) was true with a simple proof. Is it even true in the particular case of the "motivation"?
I think the question(s) is (are) interesting independently from the "motivation" (**)note that  question b) is not directly related to the motivation because $B$ is not a lattice, but I think - after reflection - that it could also leads to the aim...

(*) and (**) : I will give more details about the link between "questions" and "motivation" in the comments if anyone needs it, but the post is quite long already...

Comment: I'd say that this question belongs on MSE -- not on MO.

Comment: If the answer is trivial it has to be "no" (because if it is "yes" it gives an elementary proof of a statement known as very difficult, and it's necessary NOT below resarch level to give such a proof).

Comment: Anyway, the characterization  of the couple (A,B) that have this property for all F and $\phi$ should not be a simple problem, and It would be quite strange to state that it's a question with no interest or a useless characterization

Comment: I posted as you adviced on MSE with few modifications... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577440/decreasing-family-of-families-with-lower-bound-zero  I hope that I will get an answer but also understand what make this question not for MO... Maybe the characterisation of $(A,B,\psi)$ that satisfy question a) is a well known concept?